# What is the best way to create a smooth notification window in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, window, notifications

...similar to those produced by email clients like thunderbird or outlook, sliding up or fading in from the tray.

Comment: Which GUI toolkit are you using?  I imagine that would make a difference...

Comment: none yet. Currently, the application is just in my head, I am not completely sure of the technical setup yet (depends on this question, actually, among other things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple popup:  Look at http://jtoaster.sourceforge.net/

For the fancy stuff look at what Java 2D can do:

http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/samples/java2demo/Java2Demo.html

Check Composite -> Composite FadeAnim.

Answer (score 0):

What are your notifications for? Is it for a program that already exists, or are you writing a new application?

I ask because Adobe AIR has some functionality for doing this sort of thing, either as a Flex based application, or an AIR application written in HTML/JS. But, you wouldn't use AIR unless this is something you were building from the ground up.

Comment: Well, actually I will build it from ground up, and the notifications will be an important part of the app, so that they would really influence the technique I'd choose... however, even though I not bad with JS, AIR is one of the things I have absolutely no experience with...

Comment: If you are a good programmer with decent knowledge of HTML and JavaScript, then writing an AIR application is pretty basic really. Especially if you use the Aptana plugin in Eclipse, with AIR support. It can create a new project for you in moments, which includes some nice sample code to get you started, and the AIR api stuff is ultimately just like working with any other JS library. Adobe has a really nice help center setup in their Adobe Developer Center, targeted at those working with HTML/JS.

Answer (score 0):

Swing's Timer class (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) can be used for rudimentary animation - just use the timer to update the location of the panel containing your content.

I attended a JavaOne session last year where they did some pretty slick stuff with this.

Slides : http://progx.org/users/Gfx/FilthierRicherClientier.pdf

pay special attention to page 29 and on.

And here's a website from the same folks, but with more code and screenshots, etc...

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/23/create-moving-experiences-with-animated-transitions.html

The end result of all of this was very, very slick.